# How can I prevent nix-copy-closure from prompting for a password on CI

Tags: bash, ssh, travis-ci, nix

I'm trying to build and then copy over a package from Travis-CI to my EC2 instance.

I've followed [these steps](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-travis/blob/master/encrypted-ssh-keys-deployment.md) for setting up my ssh key.

As far as I can tell, the key is working correctly -- I'm able to run the pwd command on [line 12](https://github.com/willisplummer/haskell-nix/blob/master/.travis.yml#L12) and get the expected response of `/root`

[image]

However when I call `nix-copy-closure` I'm prompted for a password and the script hangs. In the docs for nix-copy-closure, they note that it will request a password twice and recommend using ssh-agent to address it. I thought that I was using ssh-agent. Locally, I am not prompted for a password.

I'm at a loss! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being that I needed to specify `root@$SERVER_ADDRESS` in the `--to` argument to `nix-copy-closure`. Thanks to @thoferon for the suggestion